# Chromium --no-startup-window under subprocess.Popen in python3

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, chromium

So, when you try to subprocess.Popen('chromium', '--no-startup-window') - the chromium window is still appears (and even with nasty yellow label that it wasn't shut down correctly, will you want to reopen all tabs). Why is it so and how to fix it?

Comment: your command `Popen('chromium', '--no-startup-window')` should produce `TypeError: bufsize must be an integer`. What is your actual command? (provide a complete minimal code example that demonstrates the issue)

Comment: I already did this another way (just by using os.system) but then I can't get pid of a process which makes me sad panda :/

Comment: There is no need to use `os.system()` here. Try `subprocess.check_call(['chromium', '--no-startup-window'])`. Does it work if you run `chromium --no-startup-window` from a command-line? Why do you need child's `pid`?

Comment: It works, but can I use it for processes which are actually 'daemons' and should be run in background and how can I get PIDs? I need pids because I'm writing a wrapper around my WM (wmii) and need to kill all startup processes. Here wmii.py file is responsible for startup and settings.py file contains startup strings: https://github.com/ewancoder/dotfiles/tree/master/.wmii-hg Currently I'm using 2 different functions for chromium and everything else.